# Good practices: using member routes or filter on search scopes?

Tags: design-patterns, api-design, ruby-on-rails

I want to know which practice is more convenient having the following example, (my app is a Rails app but this can be applied on any framework)
I am trying to create an endpoint which contains author posts filtered by year using an REST-API.

Having the models:

```rb
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  # attributes:
  # - id
  # - published_at (datetime)
  # - author_id
end
```

Controllers:

Solution A) (member route)

```rb
class AuthorsController < ApiController
  def posts_by_year
    @posts = Post.where(author_id: params['author_id']).by_year(params['year'])

    render json: @posts
  end
end
```

Solution B) Filter search on Posts index

```rb
class PostsController < ApiController
  def index
    @posts = posts_search_scope # this is an illustrative example, I will use a Finder service to do this

    render json: @posts
  end

 private
 def posts_search_scope
   query = Post
   unless params
     query.all
   else
     query.by_year(params['year']) if params['year']
     query.where(author_id: params['author_id']) if params['author_id')
     query
   end
 end
end
```

I like more the solution B but i'm concerned that, as Post model grows, I need to support more and more search params and business rules.

Comment: Why do you consider solution A to be non-restful?

Comment: you're right, this is a restful member action, my bad